# How is "quod" operating in this sentence of Hyginus?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-identification

The first sentence of Hyginus' Prometheus is:

> Hominés anteá ab immortálibus ignem petébant neque in perpetuum serváre sciébant; quod posteá Prometheus in ferulá détulit in terrás, hominibusque mónstrávit quómodó cinere obrutum servárent.
>
> Before, people sought fire from the immortals and didn't know how to keep it continuously [lit]; *quod* afterward, Prometheus brought it down to earth on [the end of] a fennel stalk and showed people how to keep it buried in ashes.

What is *quod* doing here? It doesn't seem to be a relative, it doesn't seem to be "since," it doesn't seem to be functioning adverbially. I realize Hyginus is hardly the stylist's stylist, but it's still bugging me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd take this as *quod* "but, though", sense VII in [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquod1).

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low-quality... is there anything else you could add to back up this interpretation?

Comment: Strangely, my original link to Lewis and Short disappeared (was edited away?), so I've added the link again. The reading "but" seems to make good sense in this context -- certainly more than any other sense of *quod* that I know of. "Before, people sought fire from the immortals... but afterward, Prometheus brought it down to earth".

Answer (score 9):

The word *quod* probably means 'therefore' (or ['in respect of which'](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1013718)).
(My dictionary mentions this meaning but gives no examples.)
This would imply that Prometheus was dissatisfied with the situation described before the semicolon and therefore took action.

Another possibility is that *quod* is a relative pronoun referring to *ignis*.
That would make *quod* the object of *detulit*.
The problem is that *ignis* is masculine, so it should be *quem* instead.
I can offer three explanations:

- It is a later copy error. It was originally *quem* but it was "corrected" to *quod* which more often begins a sentence.
- Neuter was chosen because *ignis* is inanimate.

It would explain the form if *quod* refers to the whole preceding sentence or something other than *ignis*, but that doesn't make much sense as the object.

Comment: These are all great suggestions, but I'm not sure I buy them. For "in respect of which," latinlexicon.org (I love them, by the way!) gives two Terence examples, "quod me accusat, sum extra noxiam" and "siquid est Quod meā operā opus sit vobis," in which *quod* seems to be operating as a relative in a way that I don't think works here. Hyginus was a contemporary of Augustine, and I don't *think* inanimate objects were taking neuter pronouns in Latin at that time. A scribal error seems possible, but it's such an obvious one, wouldn't it have been corrected by now?